# What is the access code for David/Davis Barnes's safe?

Tags: wasteland-2

In Damonta, in the painting workshop of the person alternately referred to as David Barnes and Davis Barnes, to whom Sarah from the Canyon of Titan asks her pendant to be delivered, there is a code-locked safe.  What is its access code?  (I was expecting <kbd>SARAH</kbd>, to be honest, but no dice.)

Answer (score 4):

The code is 152260.  There's a paper object on the table nearby that indicates there are dog-eared pages.  The page numbers are the code.